# Angular: Structural Directive with injected child component does not change that component onChanges with directive's @Input()

Tags: angular

Hi I currently begrudgingly have to write a structural directive, which in it will dynamically create and inject a child component has inputs and has `ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush`.The insertion so far works as expected as I am able to use a combination of `ViewDetectorRef.createComponent` and `Renderer2`'s `appendChildMethod` to inject in the right location.

Just like any other component or directive, I expect that if I have inputs, and they change,  the UI should refresh itself based on the changed inputs. In the case of this situation, I theoretically should be able to update the child component's input using  `ngOnChanges()` and manually performing the update and the component UI should update itself.

However with all of our components using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush` this update mentioned above does not seem to work and the UI stays the same as if it doesn't change at all.

I have tried the same code without the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush` on my components and they update as expected.

I have also tried using `changeDetectorRef`'s `markForCheck()` method after I manually update the inputs and again they fail to change the UI.

I have created a minimalistic example that simulates current problem showing a very similar directive setup and a button to increment counts in a child component. It is expected that when you click on the increment button, the count, inside the child injected component should update itself increasing the count by 1 each time.

I have 2 versions:

1. https://stackblitz.com/edit/updating-input-inside-inject-child-compoennt-no-cd-onpush?file=app%2Ffoo.directive.ts - has the results as expected without the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush`
2. https://stackblitz.com/edit/updating-input-inside-inject-child-compoennt-with-cd-onpush?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts - has the results NOT as expected and with the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush` being used

Some help or explanation on this `ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush` to resolve the issue would be great.

Thanks.